# Showing that $\arctan x = \arcsin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Since I don't have the answer to this one, I want to make sure I've done this correctly.

> Show that 
>   $$\arctan x = \arcsin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right)$$

Since 
$$\arctan x = \arcsin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right)$$ 
we have 
$$\tan\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right)\right) = x$$

Applying the Pythagorean theorem, we learn that $b = 1$, so we have $\tan(x/1) = x$.

It may be a bit short, but I really want to be sure I have this right before I continue on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the definitions of arcsine and arctangent.

Let $\arctan x = \theta$.  Then $\theta$ is the unique angle in the interval $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ such that $\tan\theta = x$.

Let 
$$\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right) = \varphi$$
Then $\varphi$ is the unique angle in the interval $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ such that 
$$\sin\varphi = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}$$

We need to show that $\theta = \varphi$.

Observe that 
$$\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right)^2 = \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2} < 1$$
for every real number $x$ since 
$$\frac{x^2}{1 + x^2} < 1 \iff x^2 < 1 + x^2 \iff 0 < 1$$
Hence, 
$$-1 < \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} < 1 \implies -\frac{\pi}{2} < \varphi = \arcsin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right) < \frac{\pi}{2}$$

By the Pythagorean identity $\sin^2\varphi + \cos^2\varphi = 1$, 
\begin{align*}
\cos^2\varphi & = 1 - \sin^2\varphi\\
              & = 1 - \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\right)^2\\
              & = 1 - \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}\\
              & = \frac{1 + x^2 - x^2}{1 + x^2}\\
              & = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}
\end{align*}
Since $-\frac{\pi}{2} < \varphi < \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\cos\varphi > 0$, so we take the positive square root.  Thus,
$$\cos\varphi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}$$
Hence, 
\begin{align*}
\tan\varphi & = \frac{\sin\varphi}{\cos\varphi}\\
            & = \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}}\\
            & = x\\
            & = \tan\theta
\end{align*}
Since $\theta$ is the unique angle in the interval $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ such that $\tan\theta = x$, $\tan\varphi = x$, and $-\frac{\pi}{2} < \varphi < \frac{\pi}{2}$, we may conclude that $\theta = \varphi$.

Answer (score 2):

The connection is way more *revealing* in its simplicty if you just use trigonometry. For $x$ positive take a right-angled triangle with sides $\overline{AB} = 1$ and $\overline{BC} = x$. Then by definition
$$\angle CAB = \arctan x.$$
The hypotenuse measures $\overline{AC} = \sqrt{1+x^2}$, by Pythagorean Theorem. So the same angle can be also defined as
$$\angle CAB = \arcsin \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right).$$
For negative $x$ take $\overline{BC} = -x$ and recall the odd symmetry of both sine and tangent. As easy as that.

Comment: Consider me extremely daft, but is my solution right or not?

Comment: @Learner. Don't worry. It's always better to really clarify things. Your statements are a little bit confusing. E.g: "Since... we have...". It should rather read something like: "What I need to demonstrate, that is... is equivalent to...". Also, I always recommend not to use symbols without definitions (unless it is something really *standard*, like $\pi$). So you should also state what $b$ is.

Comment: @Learner, also.. thinking about that: $$\arctan x = y$$ and $$\tan y = x$$ aren't properly *equivalent* equations. They are *only if* you limit the tangent domain.

Answer (score 1):

$\tan \arcsin \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} = \frac{\sin}{\cos} \arcsin \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\cos \arcsin \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}$ and we know that $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1 $ so $\cos x= \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}$

so $ \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\cos \arcsin \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}} = \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \arcsin \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}}=\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}}}  = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2+1}}} = x$

Comment: Ok, so basically my approach is so incorrect, it's 'not even wrong' :)

Comment: Correct, but a bit too convoluted for a simple trigonometric fact as this, don't you agree?